# How network hashrate is being calculated?

Tags: blockchain, mining, hash, networkid

**Hashrate**
The number of attempts that miner makes per second is known as the hash rate or hash power.
**Network's hashrate** 
It is the most important data point in blockchain tech. ... Essentially, the hashrate describes how much computing power (called hashing power in blockchain speak) is being thrown at the network, by nodes all across the world.

consider there are 10 nodes in the network with each has hashing power of 60h/s

then how the Network's hashrate is being calculated?

If 2 nodes out of 10 goes down, is that effects the Network's hashrate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are 10 nodes mining with 60h/s, then the total network hash rate is 10 * 60h/s = 600h/s. If 2 of those nodes go down, then the total network hash rate is 8 * 60h/s = 480h/s.

However, in practice you don't know the hash rate of of all individual nodes, so you have to rely on estimation techniques (See [How is average network hashrate determined?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18162/how-is-average-network-hashrate-determined))

Comment: If out of 10 miners, one had found out the nonce, which matches with the target... Will it share this information to only miner node or to all the nodes on the network. And when the miner( who finds the nonce )will add the newly mined block to his ledger.